# In Excel, how do I check if a cell is in a list of values (a range of cells)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got a range (A3:A10) that contains names, and I'd like to check if the contents of another cell (D1) matches one of the names in my list.

I've named the range A3:A10 'some_names', and I'd like an excel formula that will give me True/False or 1/0 depending on the contents.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

My preferred answer (modified from Ian's) is:

```
=COUNTIF(some_names,D1)>0
```

which returns TRUE if D1 is found in the range some_names at least once, or FALSE otherwise.

(COUNTIF returns an integer of how many times the criterion is found in the range)

Answer (score 100):

> =COUNTIF(some_names,D1)

should work (1 if the name is present - more if more than one instance).

Comment: how can I modify the formula so that it works in the case where the  `some_names` contains 2 columns, and also instead of D1 I have D1:E1?

Answer (score 37):

I know the OP specifically stated that the list came from a range of cells, but others might stumble upon this while looking for a specific range of values.

You can also look up on specific values, rather than a range using the [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) function.  This will give you the number where this matches (in this case, the second spot, so 2).  It will return #N/A if there is no match.

```
=MATCH(4,{2,4,6,8},0)
```

You could also replace the first four with a cell.  Put a 4 in cell A1 and type this into any other cell.

```
=MATCH(A1,{2,4,6,8},0)
```

Comment: Very nice.  Don't forget to add "quotes" if your value isn't a number (took me a couple tries to sort that out).

Comment: Sadly you can't use this in conditional formatting :(

Comment: Sure you can.  With Excel 2007 and later, you can use the IFERROR function.    =IFERROR(MATCH(A1,{2,4,6,8},0),0)  Then, you can do your conditional formatting on whether that cell =0 or >0, whichever you prefer.

Comment: `=OR(4={2,4,6,8})`

Comment: This answer is clear that the solution returns #N/A - that is true.  But is seems unhelpful: you can't use #N/A in an if clause, so you can't say IF(MATCH(4{2,3},0), "yay", "boo")... the answer is #N/A not "boo"

Comment: That just needs a level of error checking.  This will return a 0 if you get N/A, then you can do your normal if statement.   =IF(IFNA(MATCH(4,{2,4,6,8},0), 0), "yay", "boo").  Or you use @Slai's suggestion and don't use MATCH.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to turn the countif into some other output (like boolean) you could also do:

> =IF(COUNTIF(some_names,D1)>0, TRUE, FALSE)

Enjoy!

Comment: The TRUE and FALSE help indicate what needs to be replaced

Answer (score 12):

there is a nifty little trick returning Boolean in case range `some_names` could be specified explicitly such in `"purple","red","blue","green","orange"`:

```
=OR("Red"={"purple","red","blue","green","orange"})
```

Note this is NOT an array formula

Comment: Actually, it ***is*** an array formula. What it's not is an array *entered* formula ;-)

Answer (score 9):

For variety you can use MATCH, e.g.

`=ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,A3:A10,0))`

Answer (score 2):

You can nest `--([range]=[cell])` in an `IF`, `SUMIFS`, or `COUNTIFS` argument. For example, `IF(--($N$2:$N$23=D2),"in the list!","not in the list")`. I believe this might use memory more efficiently.

Alternatively, you can wrap an `ISERROR` around a `VLOOKUP`, all wrapped around an `IF` statement. Like, `IF( ISERROR ( VLOOKUP() ) , "not in the list" , "in the list!" )`.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this, I only want to be alerted to possible errors, so I would solve the situation this way ...

```
=if(countif(some_names,D1)>0,"","MISSING")
```

Then I'd copy this formula from `E1` to `E100`. If a value in the `D` column is not in the list, I'll get the message MISSING but if the value exists, I get an empty cell. That makes the missing values stand out much more.

Answer (score 0):

Array Formula version (enter with Ctrl + Shift + Enter):

```
=OR(A3:A10=D1)
```

Comment: This works.  I think it got a downvote because the downvoter did not know how to enter an array formula...  it should look like {=OR(R34:R36=T34)} after it's entered, if you entered it corretly