# In Excel, checking if a cell matches one item from a named constant string list

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, countif

This question is an expansion on [In Excel, how do I check if a cell is in a list of values (a range of cells)](https://superuser.com/questions/601419/in-excel-how-do-i-check-if-a-cell-is-in-a-list-of-values-a-range-of-cells) .

I'm trying to do `=COUNTIF(name,G6)` and when name refers to some cells, it works fine, but when it refers to my constant string array it gives `#VALUE!`

My constant string array (using the name manager) is `={"192.168.3.2","192.168.3.10"}`... etc, and that may be my problem...

Thanks

Comment: A good answer to this is in the answers of the same linked question: https://superuser.com/a/838379/150277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, but I got my answer from Stack Overflow here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293184/in-excel-countif-not-working-with-constant-defined-string?noredirect=1#comment35656073_23293184

I should have just posted there, but I started here because the original question was on Stack Exchange.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple criteria for a `countif()` you might be better off using a [`COUNTIFS()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx). e.g.

`COUNTIFS(A6:G6,192.168.3.2,A6:G6,192.168.3.10)`

if you're defining an array and using numerical values (`192.168.3.2`), you don't need to use the quotation marks. Those should only be used for text values, unless your lookup array is stored as text. **Try it without the quotation marks**.